# Swift nil value != nil at same time

Tags: swift, xcode

Looking at Xcode (11.1) debug area.

[image]

Var **questionnaire is nil**, but expression `questionnaire == nil` **is false**.

Var client at the same time have another behavior

Is there something I don't see?

Comment: As I see it, though I'm not a swift expert, it looks like you are assigning `agents.dbQuestinnaries` to `questionnaire` - and that operation is returning a nil, it's not saying that the variable is nil.

Comment: There are some bugs with nil values in LLDB in Xcode 11 so maybe this is part of that. Could you show the code needed to test this and describe how to create the expressions?

Comment: @fredrik, that doesn't make sense

Comment: maybe `questionnaire` is **lazy**. Reverse to order of checking and see the result.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini no, it's not **lazy**. `var questionnaire: dbQuestionnaires? = nil`

Comment: It's likely `questionnaire` is _shadowed_. That is, there are actually two variables of that name in different scopes (e.g. your function and another one in an `if`).